# Comparing 2 excel sheets and returning a data

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to compare two Excel sheets, Sheet1 column O to Sheet2 column A:M, if it found a match, it will copy Sheet 2 "down cell of matched data" (ie match data A3, copy A4) then paste to Sheet 1 column R.  I'm (very) new to VBA and Macros so I don't know how to do this. Thanks in advance!

In sheet 1 of column O - datas are USD,JPY,TWD, etc. In sheet 2 column A to M, a specified exchange rate per currency. If sheet 1 column O data is USD, it will search in Sheet 2 with matching "USD"; if cell A3's data is USD, the exchange rate is in cell A4 which will be copied and pasted into column R of Sheet 1 corresponding to the row of USD.

So what I'm dealing with is something kind of like this:

[image: Before]

This is what I’m looking for after the macro

[image: After]

Since Sheet 1’s cell O1 matches Sheet 2’s cell A3, I want it to return Sheet 2’s cell A4’ s value and paste it to corresponding row of Sheet 1’s cell R1.

Let me know if this makes sense or if you need further clarification.
Thanks!

Comment: Your description is quite confusing. What have you tried so far? Any code you can show? Maybe an image to help visualise desired output?

Comment: I don't really understand what you want. could you be more clear please?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Most of the code you need you can manage by yourself using macro recorder:

1. Start recording new macro
2. Select cell O1
3. Copy selected cell (by pressing RMB or ctrl+C)
4. Go to Sheet2
5. Select your data (A3:M7) with mouse
6. Press ctrl+F to open "Find" window
7. Paste value of copied cell
8. Press Enter. Cell with searched value should be selected
9. Press down arrow to move selection one cell down
10. Copy value from selected cell
11. Go to Sheet1
12. Press right arrow to move to column R
13. Paste copied value
14. Stop recording the macro

After that you need to find how to use `For` loops and add it to your code. Good luck!

Comment: I can't get the code wherein after it find the matched data in sheet 2 it will copy the one cell below the matched data.

Comment: Please, add your code to your question, so we can see what is the problem.

Comment: Dim LR As Long, i As Long
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        LR = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To LR
            With .Range("A" & i)
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("Sheet2").Select
            Range("A8:M34").Select
            
            ???
            
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("Sheet1").Select
            With .Range("B" & i).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            End With
            End With
        Next i
    End With
Thanks.

Comment: Add it to your **question**, please. You can edit your question with `edit` link just below the question.

Comment: @Lyn I checked your code and: 1) You're using `With... End With` in wrong way. It's for simplifying code, but you try to select some cells. Instead of `With some_text` use `some_text.Select`. Only the first `With Sheets("Sheet1")` is used properly. 2) The missing part are points 6 to 9. Try it and tell where is the problem (if any).